# How to print the bytes while the file is being downloaded ? -golang

Tags: go, byte

I'm wondering if it's possible to count and print the number of bytes downloaded while the file is being downloaded.

```
out, err := os.Create("file.txt")
defer out.Close()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprint(err))
    panic(err)
}
resp, err := http.Get("http://example.com/zip")
defer resp.Body.Close()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprint(err))
    panic(err)
}

n, er := io.Copy(out, resp.Body)
if er != nil {
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprint(err))
}
fmt.Println(n, "bytes ")
```

Comment: Perhaps you could expand on your question, rather than pad it with filler?  What have you tried?  What isn't working?

Comment: I screamed at the computer but it didn't work :)

Comment: What does "print the bytes" mean? The bytes of the file being downloaded? Some arbitrary data? Count of bytes downloaded so far? What?

Comment: yeah, to count of bytes downloaded so far. I though it is obvious

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you wish to display the number of bytes read, while the data is transferring. Presumably to maintain some kind of a progress bar or something. In which case, you can use Go's compositional data structures to wrap the reader or writer in a custom `io.Reader` or `io.Writer` implementation.

It simply forwards the respective `Read` or `Write` call to the underlying stream, while doing some additional work with the `(int, error)` values returned by them. Here is an example you can run on the [Go playground](http://play.golang.org/p/1LAEuOS-09).

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

// PassThru wraps an existing io.Reader.
//
// It simply forwards the Read() call, while displaying
// the results from individual calls to it.
type PassThru struct {
    io.Reader
    total int64 // Total # of bytes transferred
}

// Read 'overrides' the underlying io.Reader's Read method.
// This is the one that will be called by io.Copy(). We simply
// use it to keep track of byte counts and then forward the call.
func (pt *PassThru) Read(p []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := pt.Reader.Read(p)
    pt.total += int64(n)

    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println("Read", n, "bytes for a total of", pt.total)
    }

    return n, err
}

func main() {
    var src io.Reader    // Source file/url/etc
    var dst bytes.Buffer // Destination file/buffer/etc

    // Create some random input data.
    src = bytes.NewBufferString(strings.Repeat("Some random input data", 1000))

    // Wrap it with our custom io.Reader.
    src = &PassThru{Reader: src}

    count, err := io.Copy(&dst, src)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    fmt.Println("Transferred", count, "bytes")
}
```

The output it generates is this:

```
Read 512 bytes for a total of 512
Read 1024 bytes for a total of 1536
Read 2048 bytes for a total of 3584
Read 4096 bytes for a total of 7680
Read 8192 bytes for a total of 15872
Read 6128 bytes for a total of 22000
Transferred 22000 bytes
```

Comment: You are assuming that if `err != nil` then `n == 0`. That's not necessarily true. [Package io type Reader](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader): Read reads up to len(p) bytes into p. It returns the number of bytes read (0 <= n <= len(p)) and any error encountered.

Comment: Does `pt.Reader.Read` actually read from the network though? After `http.Get` returns a response, is the download complete? The OP said, "while the file is being downloaded".

Comment: is there any way that the src = "/tmp/some-file.pdf" ? someone please?

Comment: is it possible to instrument tcp connections(net.Dial) too? as I m getting "does not implement net.Conn (missing Close method)" error when I try to instrument the conn reader object

Answer (score 22):

The stdlib now provides something like jimt's `PassThru`: [io.TeeReader](https://golang.org/pkg/io#TeeReader).  It helps simplify things a bit:

```
// WriteCounter counts the number of bytes written to it.
type WriteCounter struct {
    Total int64 // Total # of bytes transferred
}

// Write implements the io.Writer interface.  
// 
// Always completes and never returns an error.
func (wc *WriteCounter) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
    n := len(p)
    wc.Total += int64(n)
    fmt.Printf("Read %d bytes for a total of %d\n", n, wc.Total)
    return n, nil
}

func main() {

    // ...    

    // Wrap it with our custom io.Reader.
    src = io.TeeReader(src, &WriteCounter{})

    // ...
}
```

[playground](http://play.golang.org/p/InaWYEZXBO)

Comment: `io.TeeReader` is definitely the way to go these days; this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

The [grab](http://github.com/cavaliercoder/grab) Go package implements progress updates (and many other features) for file downloads.

An example of printing progress updates while a download is in process is included in the following walkthrough: http://cavaliercoder.com/blog/downloading-large-files-in-go.html

You can basically call `grab.GetAsync` which downloads in a new Go routine and then monitor the `BytesTransferred` or `Progress` of the returned `grab.Response` from the calling thread.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have explained about `PassThru`. Just provide a full example with callback function base on [Dave Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34542471/1099314)'s answer.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

// writeCounter counts the number of bytes written to it.
type writeCounter struct {
    total      int64 // total size
    downloaded int64 // downloaded # of bytes transferred
    onProgress func(downloaded int64, total int64)
}

// Write implements the io.Writer interface.
//
// Always completes and never returns an error.
func (wc *writeCounter) Write(p []byte) (n int, e error) {
    n = len(p)
    wc.downloaded += int64(n)
    wc.onProgress(wc.downloaded, wc.total)
    return
}

func newWriter(size int64, onProgress func(downloaded, total int64)) io.Writer {
    return &writeCounter{total: size, onProgress: onProgress}
}

func main() {
    client := http.DefaultClient
    url := "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerFun.mp4"
    saveTo := "/Users/tin/Desktop/ForBiggerFun.mp4"

    download(client, url, saveTo, func(downloaded, total int64) {
        fmt.Printf("Downloaded %d bytes for a total of %d\n", downloaded, total)
    })
}

func download(client *http.Client, url, filePath string, onProgress func(downloaded, total int64)) (err error) {
    // Create file writer
    file, err := os.Create(filePath)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()

    // Determinate the file size
    resp, err := client.Head(url)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    contentLength := resp.Header.Get("content-length")
    length, err := strconv.Atoi(contentLength)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    // Make request
    resp, err = client.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // pipe stream
    body := io.TeeReader(resp.Body, newWriter(int64(length), onProgress))
    _, err = io.Copy(file, body)
    return err
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Base @Dave Jack

I add progress value and receiving file data from NC (direct TCP data transfer）

```
// WriteCounter counts the number of bytes written to it.
type WriteCounter struct {
 Total      int64 // Total # of bytes transferred
 Last       int64
 LastUpdate time.Time
}

// Write implements the io.Writer interface.
//
// Always completes and never returns an error.
func (wc *WriteCounter) Write(p []byte) (int, error) {
  n := len(p)
  wc.Total += int64(n)
  now := time.Now()
  duration := now.Sub(wc.LastUpdate).Seconds()
  if duration > 1 {
    wc.LastUpdate = now

    rate := float64(wc.Total-wc.Last) / (duration) / 1024.0
    wc.Last = wc.Total

    fmt.Printf("Read %d bytes for a total of %d , Rate  %.1fKb/s \n", n, wc.Total, rate)
  }

 return n, nil
}

func Server(dest string) {
  outputFile, err := os.Create(dest)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
  }
  defer outputFile.Close()
  fileWriter := bufio.NewWriter(outputFile)

  serverListener, err := net.Listen("tcp", "0.0.0.0:"+PORT)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
  }
  defer serverListener.Close()

  serverConn, err := serverListener.Accept()
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
  }
  defer serverConn.Close()

  wc := &WriteCounter{}
  reader := io.TeeReader(serverConn, wc)
  serverConnReader := bufio.NewReaderSize(reader, 32*1024*1024)

  io.Copy(fileWriter, serverConnReader)
  fileWriter.Flush()
  outputFile.Sync()
  fmt.Println("Done: Writer")
 }
```