# Track and show downloading file summary ( in percentage ) - Go lang

Tags: arrays, io, go, byte

I'm doing a process that downloads a file via a url parameter passed. download is being done properly but what i cant do is to print a summary of the percentage of download done. ( every second )

ive built one simulated kind of this summary but its not download anything, its just to show how i want it.

i tried to bring io.copy inside my source so i could change it ant print while the copy is being done, but it fails.

can someone help me?
thanks

```
 package main

    import (
        "fmt"
        "io"
        "net/http"
        "os"
        "strings"
    //  "time"
    )

    func downloadFromUrl(url string) {
        tokens := strings.Split(url, "/")
        fileName := tokens[len(tokens)-1]
        fmt.Println("Downloading", url, "to", fileName)

    //create file
    output, err := os.Create(fileName)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error while creating", fileName, "-", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Creating", fileName)
    defer output.Close()

    //get url
    response, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error while downloading", url, "-", err)
        return
    }           
    defer response.Body.Close()

    //copy and bytes        
    n, err := io.Copy(output, response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error while downloading", url, "-", err)
        return
    }

        //track progress
        for i := 1; float64(i) < float64(n); i++ {
            fmt.Println("",float64(i),float64(n))
            percent := float64(i) / (float64(n) / float64(100))
            percentTot := fmt.Sprintf(" %#.02f%% ", percent)
            fmt.Println(percentTot,"downloaded\n")
            //time.Sleep(3000 * time.Millisecond)
        }   


    }

    func main() {
        //read args 
        args := os.Args

        //loop args
        for i := 1; i < len(args); i++ {
            url := args[i]
            //call download         
            downloadFromUrl(url)        
        }
    }


**Output:**
go run main.go http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/AD.zip
Downloading http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/AD.zip to AD.zip
Creating AD.zip
 1 64639
 0.00%  downloaded

 2 64639
 0.00%  downloaded

 3 64639
 0.00%  downloaded

 4 64639
 0.01%  downloaded

 5 64639
 0.01%  downloaded
```

Answer (score 8):

I have done that in my [senvgo project](https://github.com/VonC/senvgo/blob/56346c5d77cffdb7f5bee74247cefbcff3356859/main.go#L2019-L2028) with a `io.Reader` wrapper

```
// PassThru wraps an existing io.Reader.
//
// It simply forwards the Read() call, while displaying
// the results from individual calls to it.
type PassThru struct {
    io.Reader
    total    int64 // Total # of bytes transferred
    length   int64 // Expected length
    progress float64
}
```

You define a `Read()` method on that wrapper (to make it an `io.Reader`)

```
// Read 'overrides' the underlying io.Reader's Read method.
// This is the one that will be called by io.Copy(). We simply
// use it to keep track of byte counts and then forward the call.
func (pt *PassThru) Read(p []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := pt.Reader.Read(p)
    if n > 0 {
        pt.total += int64(n)
        percentage := float64(pt.total) / float64(pt.length) * float64(100)
        i := int(percentage / float64(10))
        is := fmt.Sprintf("%v", i)
        if percentage-pt.progress > 2 {
            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, is)
            pt.progress = percentage
        }
    }

    return n, err
}
```

And you use that `io.Reader` to read the [`Response`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response) (result of your http request):

```
client := &http.Client{
    CheckRedirect: redirectPolicyFunc,
}
response, err := client.Get("http://example.com/something/large.zip")
defer response.Body.Close()
readerpt := &PassThru{Reader: response.Body, length: response.ContentLength}
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(readerpt)
```

The `ReadAll()` call triggers the actual download, and the `PassThru.Read()` will print the % downloaded against the expected length (`response.ContentLength`)

---

Inspirations:

- this [<kbd>play.golang.org</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/1LAEuOS-09) for the Copy() function
- "[How to print the bytes while the file is being downloaded ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22422650/6309)"

Comment: You seem to be assuming that if `err == nil` then `n == 0`. That's not necessarily true. [Package io type Reader](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader): Read reads up to len(p) bytes into p. It returns the number of bytes read (0 <= n <= len(p)) and any error encountered.

Comment: @peterSO I don't follow: where do you see `n == 0` if `err == nil` in the code above?

Comment: In `func (pt *PassThru) Read(p []byte) (int, error)` you have `if err == nil { pt.total += int64(n) }`. You do not add `n` to `pt.total` if `err != nil`, you should.

Comment: CORRECTION s/err == nil/err != nil/: You seem to be assuming that if `err != nil` then `n == 0`. That's not necessarily true. Package io type Reader: Read reads up to len(p) bytes into p. It returns the number of bytes read (0 <= n <= len(p)) and any error encountered

Comment: @peterSO I guessed that eventually (which is why I didn't follow you initially).  The relevant doc is: "Callers should always process the `n > 0` bytes returned before considering the error `err`. Doing so correctly handles I/O errors that happen after reading some bytes and also both of the allowed EOF behaviors."

Comment: How could I use this with io.Copy?  ioutil.Writefile reads the entire file into memory then dumps it to disk. I want to write the file as it's being downloaded.

Comment: @gregf not sure, actually. Could you make that in its own question?